# localization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I know that in **Rails**, we can put localization file under `config/locales` to achieve the localization purpose.

For example `config/locales/en.yml` contains all the text in **English** and `config/locales/fr.yml` contains all the text in **French**.

But how about **Chinese**? If I would like to make a web app. which also has Chinese version, is it so that I just simply translate all texts into Chinese then put it under `config/locales/ch.yml` ? Any other sophisticated way for app. Chinese localization ?

Comment: filenames for Chinese are `zh.yml`, `zh-CN.yml`, `zh-TW.yml`

Answer (score 1):

As zed_0xff said, you need to call the file with `zh` as the language. To translate content, copy the en.yml file to zh.yml (for example), translate the content into Chinese, then set the locale to 'zh' within your app.

Answer (score 0):

For rails-i18n, you can find the [`zh-CN.yml`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/zh-CN.yml) (China Chinese) and [`zh-TW.yml`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/zh-TW.yml) (Taiwan Chinese variant) on GitHub. These files include the basic translations for ActiveRecord, numbers, dates, etc.

All you would need to do is drop them under your config/locales folder. You would also need to add any translations that your app requires.